# Bridging Kafka and Akka Streams

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, akka, kafka-consumer-api, akka-stream

Kafka Streams are only supported on the JVM platform. So I am looking for a way to leverage Akka Streams in C# to build a Kafka consumer with the benefit from Akka Streams.

The Confluent C# Kafka consumer is based on polling and event handling, e.g.

```
using (var consumer = new Consumer<Null, string>(consumerConfig, null, new StringDeserializer(Encoding.UTF8)))
{
    // Subscribe to the OnMessage event
    consumer.OnMessage += (obj, msg) =>
    {
        // handle message
    };

    consumer.Subscribe(new List<string>() { kafkaTopic });

    while (!cancelled)
    {
        consumer.Poll();
    }
}
```

and the source for Akka Streams seems to be based on IEnumerable. Since polling and IEnumerable is similar in nature it must somehow be possible to bridge these two technologies. I am new to Akka Streams and have not be able to figure out how to do this. Any ideas or hints about how to proceed are most welcome.